# Delay and redirect

Tags: codeigniter

Is there anyway to display set flash data message first and then redirect to new page after a 5 secs delay in controller.

```
echo "Message";
sleep(5);
redirect();
```

Thanks

Comment: try this `header( "refresh:5;url=abc.php" );`

Answer (score 3):

When you are in your controller method to set the flashdata, send to  time ins econds :

controller.php

```
public function do_something(){
    //do somthing
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message_id', 'Message');//message rendered
    $this->session->set_flashdata('seconds_redirect', 5);//time to be redirected (in seconds)
    $this->session->set_flashdata('url_redirect', base_url('controller/method'));//url to be redirected

    redirect('folder/temp_view', 'refresh');
}
```

in your view/folder/temp_view.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?= $this->session->flashdata('seconds_redurect');?>;url=<?= $this->session->set_flashdata('url_redirect')?>" />
</head>
<body>

    <?= $this->session->flashdata('message_id');?>

</body>
</html>
```

with this you pass the message variables, time in which you want to be redirected to another page and the url to where it is redirected

Comment: Thank you so much, let me check and reply back.hope this helps

Comment: keep me informed if It runs

Answer (score 2):

Since you are loading the page, you need to use javascript to redirect.

Put this code in your html view :

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='newpage.html'},5000);</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help let me check this.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck at the same place:

1.Type this for static url in view file:

```
<?php
 header("Refresh: 5; url=\"http://www.google.com\"");
 echo "You will be redirected to google in 5 seconds...";
?>
```

2.Type this for base_url in view file :

```
<?php
  header('Refresh:5; url= '. base_url().'/create_event'); 
  echo "You will be redirected in 5 seconds...";
?>
```

//DON'T Forget to put semi-colon at end.

Comment: This one is the easiest solution to use in View file. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was helpful! @Viren Panchal and thnks fr the edit suggest!